# How to query multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to query three tables and my table structures are as below

```
Table 1: info table
  
id name  pincode
1  Lele   560099
2  John   560099
3  Marium 560077
```

```
Table 2: area table

id area pincode 
1 Nagar 560099
```

```
Table 3: Region table

id area  latitude  longitude
1  Nagar 10.23456  10.9865
```

Now what I am trying to fetch is the user count that stays in Nagar and along with that I am trying to fetch that area's lat and long. **Expected output** should be

```
usersCount areaName  pincode   lat       long
  2        Nagar     560099   10.23456  10.9865
```

So far I tried the below query:

```
select 
count(distinct info.id)as usersCount,
area.area as area_name,
are.pincode as pincode,
region.latitude as latitude,
region.longitude as longitude
from 
info, area, region
where 
area.area = "Nagar"
```

The above query gives me blank output.
I am not sure where I am going wrong in this query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the join criteria between the tables and the group by to count the users:

```
SELECT count() as usersCount, r.areaName, a.pincode, r.lat, r.long
  FROM region r
       INNER JOIN area a on a.area = r.areaName
       INNER JOIN info i on i.pincode = a.pincode
 WHERE area.area = 'Nagar'
 GROUP BY r.areaName, a.pincode, r.lat, r.long
```

Comment: is there something wrong with your data ? f.e. 'Nagar '(space) instead of 'Nagar'. Is pincode twice of the same datatype ? What if you test joining only region and area.

Comment: Yes Pincode is of same datatype in both the tables if that's what you are asking?

Comment: and is 'Nagar' the same in both tables. If you don't get a SQL error but just an empty result and all your tables have correct data, the query should return values. So check your join conditions one by one.

Comment: 'Nagar' is same in bothe places and it does not throw error. But the result comes empty

Comment: This may sound stupid but have you tested a simple `select * from area`, `select * from region` and `select * from info` ? I think your problem is not related to the query itself.

Comment: My bad I did a stupid silly mistake and beacuse of it the output was coming empty. I rectified it. Thank you your query works. Thanks a lot!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You might a correlated subquery to be helpful:

```
select r.*,
       (select count(*)
        from area a join
             info i
             on i.pincode = a.pincode
        where a.area = r.areaname
       ) as cnt
from region r
where name 'Nagar';
```

This often has better performance than a query that uses aggregation.